# dynamically add radio and dropdown list in Html with JavaScript and return data back

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a Google WebApp where I have collected a one dimensional array from spreadsheet.

Now the challenge Part is creating a radio button and dropdownList with the count of that array in HTML and pull the user input back into the spreadsheet.

Here is what I have done till now:-

Html --->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <?!= include('page-css'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
<form id="myform">
<table class="striped" width="100">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Agent</th> 
      <th>S1</th>
      <th>S2</th>
      <th>S3</th> 
      <th>Weekoff-1</th>
      <th>Weekoff-2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="perf"></tbody>
</table>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
    
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <?!= include('roster-js'); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

and finally where I need help JavaScript front end side:->

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getRosterData).loadRoster();
//getTable1Data(data);
});


function getRosterData(dataArray) {

let weeksArray = ["sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday"];

let tbody = document.getElementById("perf");

dataArray.forEach(function(ele) {
  // creating row element for each agent
  const tableRow = document.createElement("tr");
  
  // create td elements
  var agentTD = document.createElement("td");
  agentTD.setAttribute("id", "agent"+ ele);
  var t = document.createTextNode(ele);
  agentTD.appendChild(t);
  
  // create td elements with unique ids
  var s1TD = document.createElement("td");
  s1TD.appendChild(createRadioButton( "s1-" + ele));
 
  // create td elements with unique ids
  var s2TD = document.createElement("td");
  s2TD.appendChild(createRadioButton( "s2-" + ele));
  
  // create td elements with unique ids
  var s3TD = document.createElement("td");
  s3TD.appendChild(createRadioButton( "s3-" + ele));
  
  // create td elements with unique ids
  var w1TD = document.createElement("td");
  w1TD.appendChild(createDropdown("w1-" + ele));
  
   // create td elements with unique ids
  var w2TD = document.createElement("td");
  w2TD.appendChild(createDropdown("w2-" + ele));
  
  // append td to table row
  tableRow.appendChild(agentTD);
  tableRow.appendChild(s1TD);
  tableRow.appendChild(s2TD);
  tableRow.appendChild(s3TD);
  tableRow.appendChild(s3TD);
  tableRow.appendChild(w1TD);
  tableRow.appendChild(w2TD);
  
  tbody.appendChild(tableRow);
});

function createRadioButton(id) {
  //create a radio button
  var radio = document.createElement("input");
  radio.setAttribute("type", "radio");
  radio.setAttribute("id", id);
  return radio;
}

function createDropdown(id) {
  //create a radio button
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var select = document.createElement('select');
  select.setAttribute("id", id);
  weeksArray.forEach(function (day) {
    select.options.add( new Option(day, day));
  });
  fragment.appendChild(select);
  return fragment;
}

document.getElementById("myform")
}

</script>
```

This Question has gone too big. Anyways now I need help to populate a html page with the list of names that I have collected from Google Spreadsheet and Simultaneously add 3 radio buttons and a drop-down list respectively. At the end capture data if user submits form.
Please let me know if anymore clarification is required.

Here is the outcome by now :-

[image: Out Come]

Comment: I have not included that part of html. Just the part where I am stuck with the coding but if you want me to upload that was well then I will.

Comment: Sorry thanks for correcting! I am using it on server side.

Comment: well the above code is doing the job for me by creating an html file and pulling the array-data from sheet. the problem is with the the logic in JavaScript at the html side.

Comment: I learn that from a you-tube video [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9LHPU0dYyrU&list=PLv9Pf9aNgemt82hBENyneRyHnD-zORB3l&index=8) its very use please look into it.

Comment: Ok. But You should include the compete code including `var Route={}.....` at the top.

Comment: Understood!! I am going to edit my code. However My issue is not resolved @Sagar Choudhary has provided a very precise answer and it works fine for a normal form but when I integrate it in my code It does not load anything.

Comment: [Edit] to show the latest code that you've modified according to the answer provided.

Comment: I Just did Please have a look. This only loads the first column but not the entire table.

Comment: [Edit] to explain in the question itself: 1.What happens? 2.What do you expect to happen? 3.What did you do to troubleshoot? Provide browser console logs, debug info, where do you think code stops executing and why do you think so, etc...

Comment: If you're using any other frameworks/css/script srcs, disable them during development. Use plain html to test.

Comment: You are correct using this `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">` is preventing the form to load correctly. Otherwise its working fine. However, the html styling looks weird how can I prevent this from happening? any suggestion.

Comment: I would expect the issue to be in material css, not material icons. Although, I'm not familiar with material css,but I expect that you would need to reinitialize all elements after table addition.

Comment: @TheMaster I have resolved the css issue but now I am stuck with the radio button selection. Could you please help me. Now when I check all the radio buttons all the buttons are getting selected. But I want only one selection per row.

Comment: You might want to ask a new question if you're unable to solve it after reading and practicing [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio)

Comment: Great that document did the job, I grouped radio names. Now my last problem is to read the values back from form submit. and return those values to spreadsheet. I am going to ask another question for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using **Document Fragments**. you can read more about it here:
[Document Fragments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)

For e.g to create list:

```
function getRosterData(dataArray) {
  let tbody = document.getElementById('perf');

  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
  select = document.createElement('select');

  dataArray.forEach(function(r) {
    select.addChild(r, r);
  }
}
```

[Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option) is used to create options for the dropdown list.

Similarly, you can use `document.createElement()` to create radio buttons with some unique id's which you can later use to capture data when they submit it.

**Codepen**: i have created a small codepen to help out with it:
It can be view here [Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/sagarchoudhary96/pen/oNvQpZE)

Comment: Thanks for your Help @Sagar Choudhary. I would really appreciate if you would complete the loop as I am a newbie in html side. I would analyse it soon and read the document you provided.

Comment: what is the data needed to be in dropdown? is it needed to be the whole dataArray?

Comment: No its just Week Days Name `[Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Satarday,Sunday]`. Dataarray Variables are for just First Column `Agent`.

Comment: @Mask i have added a codepen link in the above answer to help you out with it. i have used data array element to create unique id's for each input element. you can use those to  get there values on submit button click.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I am able to load the table but there is one problem where all the radio buttons are getting selected how can I prevent this from happening.

Comment: @Mask that can be achieved by giving sane name attriibute to those radio button from which you want to select one. you can go through this: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp and check the first example in it.

Comment: Thanks Sagar. I solved that problem. Thanks for your effort I really appreciate that!